# variational autoencoder with limited data

Tags: tensorflow, autoencoder, data-augmentation, data-generation

Im working on a binary classificaton project, and im using VAE (variational autoencoder) to handle the imbalance between the 2 classes by generating new samples for the minority class.

the first class (majority class) contains 20000 samples, and the second one (minority class) contains 500 samples.

After training VAE model on the minority class, i generated new samples for this class and add them to the training set, then i trained two classification models, a model on trained on the imbalanced data (only training set) and the second one trained with training set + data generated by VAE). The problem is the first model is giving results better than the second(f1-score, Roc auc...), and i thought that maybe the problem was because of the limited amount of data that the VAE was trained on.

Any help please.

Answer (score 0):

Though 500 training Images are not good enough to generate diversified images from a VAE, you can still try producing some. It's better to take mean of latents of 10 different images (or even more) and pass it through the decoder ( if you're already doing this, ignore it. If you're doing some other method, try this).

If it's still not working, then, I suggest you to build a Conditional VAE on your entire dataset. In conditional VAE, you train VAE using the labels so that your models learns not only reconstruction but also what class of image it is reconstructing. This helps you to generate an Image of any particular class.

Comment: Ok, i will try your idea, but for your information, my dataset is not images, it's just a numerical dataset, where each row represents an instance. I have a another question : is there any way i can evaluate the vae without using classification ?